# Parsing simple binary file with Data.Binary.Get in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary

I am trying to parse a simple binary file in Haskell with the Data.Binary.Get monad.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
data MsgString = Definition_msg {
      msg_no        :: Word16
    } deriving (Show)

parseDef :: Get MsgString
parseDef = do
    msg_no   <- getWord16le
    return $ Definition_msg msg_no

parseMain :: Get [MsgString]
parseMain =  do
      bit <- getWord8
      msg <- parseDef
      return msg:parseMain
```

And the error I get is the following:

```
Prelude> :l example.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( example.hs, interpreted )

example.hs:23:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `[m MsgString]'
           against inferred type `Get [MsgString]'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `parseMain'
    In the expression: return msg : parseMain
    In the expression:
        do { bit <- getWord8;
             msg <- parseDef;
               return msg : parseMain }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can anyone see what I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your last line, which parses as:

```
(return msg) : parseMain
```

But that really isn't the only problem.  parseMain is of type `Get [MsgString]` when you really just want a `[MsgString]` so you must run the monadic action first:

```
parseMain :: Get [MsgString]
parseMain =  do
    bit <- getWord8
    msg <- parseDef
    rest <- parseMain
    return (msg : rest)
```

Notice this will get an infinite list of `MsgString`'s and won't terminate without an exception.  Perhaps you intended to have an if statement guarding that recursive call to `parseMain`?

Comment: Thanks!! I now see what I did wrong. :) Regarding the termination of the program - I postponed that until I had fixed this problem. Thanks again for your help!